# How keep docker container running after closing the remote connection

Tags: docker

I have a python script as a docker container on a remote machine.
To run the container, I use

```
docker run -it --rm -v ${PWD}/results:/results --name my-running-container my_img
```

The computation time is high and I want to run the container and close the remote connection, is this possible, if yes how?

Thanks

Comment: If you were directly running the Python script `./myscript.py --host 0.0.0.0`, how would you address this use case?

Comment: Thanks a lot @DavidMaze, I just knew about ```nohup python script.py & ```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add -d switch, it means run in background

```
docker run -dit --rm -v ${PWD}/results:/results --name my-running-container my_img
```

It came from help,

-d, --detach                         Run container in background and print container ID

Comment: Thank you, I will check it.